# RegistrationsController is not call my def

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, user-registration

I have this registrations_controller.rb file in a app/controllers/users folder.
What I am trying to accomplish is once some registers to immediately direct them to a profile page so they may edit their profile. But when they already have an existing account and they are just signing in it will direct them to their dashboard.

But everytime i make a new account I get this "This web page has a redirect loop" from the browser. Can anyone explain what im doing wrong?

---------registrations_controller.rb file--------

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
protected

 def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   new_profile_path(current_user)
 end
end
```

---------application.rb file--------

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   dashboards_path(current_user)
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    dashboards_path
  end
end
```

---------routes.rb file--------

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 get 'homepages/index'
 resources 'profiles'
 devise_for :users, :controller => {:registrations => "users/registrations"}

 devise_scope :user do 
   root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
 end
```

end

Comment: What's in your profiles_controller.rb ?

Comment: My index definition and my new definition but they are empty as of now.

Comment: Where is `dashboards_path` in routes file? Also, Check you log file. It will show the paths involved in redirect loop.